# How do I configure the cron daemon flags?

Tags: cron

I'd like my Ubuntu 20.04 server to run `crond` with the `-L15` flag. What's the right way to configure it to do so?

See [`man cron`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/cron.8.html).

`/etc/init.d/cron` does not give me the impression I should mess with it.

Comment: `man cron` does not mention the `-s` flag. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Updated with link to documentation. I can't find that man documentation on my system though (e.g. `man` has no entry for `crond`) so I suspect I might be looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: As the cron daemon (even in your documentation) is actually called `cron`, not `crond`, you should use `man cron`. No mention of `-s` flag there, as I already wrote. I'm afraid what you want is simply not possible.

Comment: if the idea is to log to syslog use `| /usr/bin/logger -t TAG` after your command. TAG can be used as an identifier for that cron task

Comment: @raj just as a general note, while that's true on Ubuntu, other Linux flavors do have a man page for `crond` (you get it with `man crond` or `man 8 crond`), so maybe that's why the OP was expecting one.

Comment: I guess my actual question, then, is how to configure cron to always send all output for all jobs to syslog in Ubuntu. Not sure if I should edit this question or ask a new one.

Comment: I'll create a new question and edit this one only slightly.

Comment: Asked https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367618/how-to-make-all-cron-jobs-output-to-syslog