# How to make all cron jobs output to syslog?

Tags: cron

I can configure individual cron jobs to output to syslog by making them explicitly pipe their output there, with e.g. `| /usr/bin/logger -t MYJOB`. Is there any way to make *all* cron jobs output to syslog by default?

Comment: I would suggest to put that line behind all cron job lines. The tag at the end is very useful when searching through syslog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to create a script `/usr/sbin/sendmail` that instead of sending mail, logs the contents of supposed mail message to syslog using for example `logger` command.